# Feature-rich in one word

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

I'm writing an advertising summary for my software.

Example usage:

> The software is opensource, straightforward, modular, and ______. ("Feature rich" or something that has a lot of useful options)

I would like to replace "Feature rich" with something more shorter and sexy in term of marketing.

Does "Capable" sound sweet for native speakers? I guess not really... Maybe "Flexible"?
Thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: Maybe "functionally capable"

Comment: Option-rich? Powerful? Super-useful? Dripping with options?

Comment: "Powerful" looks nice. Why did I miss it?

Comment: 'Versatile' is  another alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Powerful or Dyanamic can also have good impact but it depends a lot on what domain your software is gonna serve.
Powerful/Robust/Scalable/customizable are the buzz words most commonly seen in product taglines.
Eg. If your software is in insurance domain and can process a million forms under a minute then powerful makes sense but if it provides high customization options, Scalable or customizable sounds  great.

Comment: Can you please add more substance to this answer? Right now, it's more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: Thanks. "Powerful" won. It was originally suggested in the comments so + to both of you

Answer (score 0):

Features have to meet customer needs to be of any value.  A product that meets customer needs better than the competition usually wins.  So instead of touting features, list customer needs that your product's features satisfy.  See for example (scroll down) [The Juran Trilogy and Quality Planning Road Map](https://mbsportal.bl.uk/taster/subjareas/busmanhist/mgmtthinkers/juran.aspx).

**EDIT**

*"So instead of touting features, list customer needs that your product's features satisfy" - yes, I did. Just need a title for the list*

Customer needs satisfied by our product's features.

Comment: -1 The question is about trying to replace a word with a better one, not how to summarize a software. While being a good suggestion, it's not applicable as an answer to the question.

Comment: @Hank Yes, I know. And I answered the way I did with the full knowledge that my answer would be down voted. It is the answer that he needs to hear.  Any synonym for "feature rich" will not help him sell his product. Juan is marketing 101.

Comment: "So instead of touting features, list customer needs that your product's features satisfy" - yes, I did. Just need a title for the list